# Glass Mapper v5 not mapping Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link fields correctly

Tags: glass-mapper

We are upgrading `Sitecore to 9.3` and `glass mapper to Glass.Mapper.Sc.93 (v5.6.158-alpha)`. Having an issue with most of our `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link` types coming back as null. which used to work fine in v4. I am a total noob to glass btw.

**Here is the error:** Databases are identical except of course one has been upgraded to sc 9.3.
Taking it from the top:
[image]

Secondary navigation calls `Model.SearchPage` which is coming back as null when using Glass V5

[image]
[image]

In Glass V4 it works just fine and is not null:

[image]

Not sure if relevant but here is the mapping (identical in V4 and V5):

[image]

Here is the calling code that works in v4. `retItem.SearchPage` is populated and not null:

[image]

Here is the v5 code (I realize the ISitecoreContext is marked obsolete in v5, so I tried the following approaches to get the item in V5). All items have their .SearchPage property returned as null:
[image]

Comment: Can you please add screenshot of model in both v4 and v5 which has SearchPage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use these new services, you have to first inject them with the Sitecore dependency injection container. Maybe that is the reason why you always get null results.

There is a good blog post about it: https://www.coreysmith.co/glass-mapper-5-dependency-injection/

Also, I have written my simple solution if you are using Helix: https://passionatesitecore.blogspot.com/

So simply first inject:

```
  serviceCollection.AddScoped<ISitecoreService>(sp => new SitecoreService(Sitecore.Context.Database));
```

Then get the service:

```
public ISitecoreService GetSitecoreService() => Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISitecoreService>();
```

then use this service to map items:

```
var mappedItem = GetSitecoreService().GetItem<ClassModel>(Item);
```